# Why is the program outputting something else in the code later on?

Tags: java

```
class A { int x = 1; }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { int x = 2;}
public class classTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
A w = new A(); System.out.println(w.x);
B u = new B(); System.out.println(u.x);
C v = new C(); System.out.println(v.x);
A [] a = { new A(), new B(), new C()};
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
System.out.println(a[i].x);
}
}
```

So for this, it prints out:

```
1
1
2
1
1
1
```

Why does the variable `v` that is part of `Class C` output a different one when ran each time?  For example, in the `C v = new C(); System.out.println(v.x);` it outputs `2` and in the last loop in:

`for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    System.out.println(a[i].x);
    }`

It would print out `1`?  Why isn't the first output for running `Class C` be `1` since it extends it, so `x` would equal to `2` but then would be overwritten by having x equal to `1` from `Class B` that is extending `Class A` which runs the `x = 1`?

I am taking courses in college and we are just barely touching on this topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is generated by you declared the array of type A, then all objects will be of this type. And class type A return 1.
Maybe you should use interfaces or abstract class